# Google Maps API Positioning Issue

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm currently using the Google Maps API on the following test site:

http://www.curiousme.com/clients/harrydobbs/wordpress/

The issue i'm having is that the map is loading in a completely different position to the place that I want. Does anyone have experience in solving this and getting the map icon to appear in the middle of the map, when using a javascript content slider.

all help much appreciated!

Cheers,
Rich

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your site; is your problem that the infowindow is not perfectly on the marker, or that the infowindow and marker are not centered on your map?

If the latter, your marker is set at (51.54711, -0.07415) but your map is centered at (51.5547, -0.1400). Updating your map constructor options to match your marker might solve the problem.

Comment: If I set the marker and the centre of the map the same then I experience strange issues with the positioning. For some reason, due to the content slider I am using, this gets messed up. Is there a way to delay the map loading until the user clicks contact and that the becomes visible?

Comment: What kind of 'strange issues'? Any sort of slider or page javascript you are using shouldn't affect the positioning of the map content - are you sure that is actually the problem? If so, the first hack that comes to mind is simply setting the map center again after everything is loaded (or on click for the contact page, like you mentioned).

Comment: Thanks. I think that is what I'll need to do. - How can I set the map centre after everything has loaded, or when the user clicks on a navigation item?

Comment: Make sure you have access to your map object, then simply call map.setCenter( your_latlon_object) or map.panTo( your_latlon_object) to nicely pan to the location.